# How to escape XML content with XSL to safely output it as JSON?

Tags: xml, json, xslt, escaping

How to escape XML content with XSL to safely output it as JSON?

Comment: Again - this is much simpler to answer if you provide an example input and an example output!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I have myself found the answer on Google (literaly):

http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/